# How to customize default layouts in feathers.js

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am using `feathers.js v3.0.5` as my rest solution, created the application using `feathers-cli`

For each error code the framework has a specific *html template* including the feathers logo and styles:

- `401 Not Authenticated`
- `403 Forbidden`
- `404 Not Found`

> Is there a way to customize the default templates for errors?

I guess for index.html, I just can modify the `index.html` from `/public/` folder but for errors I did not find any sensible advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom HTML pages as documented in the [Feathers error handler documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#expresserrorhandler):

```
const { errorHandler } = require('@feathersjs/express');
const app = feathers();

// Just like Express your error middleware needs to be
// set up last in your middleware chain.
app.use(errorHandler({
    html: function(error, req, res, next) {
      // render your error view with the error object
      res.render('error', error);
    }
}));

// Set paths to custom HTML pages
app.use(errorHandler({
    html: {
      404: 'path/to/notFound.html',
      500: 'there/will/be/robots.html'
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Feathers app should be responsible for rendering an error page. As you said, Feathers is your REST/WebSocket platform. Most people use it as a data-only backend for their frontend application, or even as an API server for a full fledged Express application.

In either case, you should handle the 404 error (for example) in code and redirect / display to your 404 "UI".

Since you didn't specify too much about your app, your setup, and so on, I can't give any specifics. Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sense what you say but the idea is to hide the implementation the framework version etc... I know when you specify the content-type application/json the content negotiation mechanism start working so there is no issue...

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution is to just turn off html errors. This will return json responses which are more easily interpreted by software based consumers of your api.

**Example**

```
app.use(errorHandler({
    html: false
}));
```